# php order by custom range

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to set your own order by range?

Eg.

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "
 SELECT name
      , email
      , extension
      , phone
      , department 
   FROM {$table} 
  ORDER 
     BY department
      , name ASC
  ");
```

instead of by department itself which contains a few categories such as New Sales, Used Sales, Admin, Principal.

Could I order them in my own order that I want?

I have tried but all I get is mixed up results from the database

Comment: update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: @scaisEdge sir its currently sorting the result by department in alphabetical order. Is there no way I can set the order myself? for eg. Instead of Admin being first. I want Principal to be first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use order by field

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department 
    FROM {$table} 
   ORDER BY FIELD(department, 'first', 'my_value2' , ' New Sales', 'Used Sales' ) , name ASC");
```

in your case could be

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department 
    FROM {$table} 
   ORDER BY FIELD(department, 'Principal', 'Admin' , 'other', 'and others' ) , name ASC");
```